# How not specify an exact order of evaluation of function argument helps C & C++ compiler to generate optimized code?

Tags: c++, optimization, compiler-optimization, operator-precedence, unspecified-behavior

```
#include <iostream>
int foo() {
    std::cout<<"foo() is called\n";
    return 9;
}
int bar() {
    std::cout<<"bar() is called\n";
    return 18;
}
int main() {
    std::cout<<foo()<<' '<<bar()<<' '<<'\n';
}
// Above program's behaviour is unspecified
// clang++ evaluates function arguments from left to right: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/STnvMm1YVrrSRSsB
// g++ & MSVC++ evaluates function arguments from right to left
// so either foo() or bar() can be called first depending upon compiler.
```

Output of above program is compiler dependent. Order in which function arguments are evaluated is *unspecified*. The reason I've read about this is that it can result in highly optimized code. *How not specify an exact order of evaluation of function argument helps compiler to generate optimized code*?

AFAIK, the order of evaluation is strictly specified in languages such as Java, C#, D etc.

Comment: Actually it is specified, each op call is a separate (chained) call. They will be evaluated in an order mandated by operator precedence.

Comment: @StoryTeller: You are mistaken.

Comment: @StoryTeller: That is true for the order the functions are called. But it is not true about the order the parameters are evaluated in. `bar()` and `foo()` can be evaluated before any calls are made. The only requirement is that they are evaluated before the sequence point where they are needed.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, each operator call requires its parameters to be evaluated before the call, since the call is nested, there isn't too much freedom here.

Comment: @StoryTeller: The parameters can be evaluated before any call is made because it is all one expression. The sequence point starts at the beginning of the expression and ends at the semicolon. Parameters are sequenced before the call but there is no requirement for them to be sequenced just before the call.

Comment: @LokiAstari, each operator call returns the parameter for the next. The only freedom is with the calls to `foo()` and `bar()`

Comment: @StoryTeller: All of the operands can be evaluated (in any order) before any of the calls.

Comment: @StoryTeller: _"each operator call returns the parameter for the next"_ The left-hand operand, yes.... not the right-hand one, which in each case is the one we're interested in.

Comment: @StoryTeller: That is what the question is about. foo() and bar can be sequenced before all the calls. Or just before they are used after other calls are made. They can be sequenced in any order in relation to each other.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: What's wrong with my question?

Comment: Long story short. If the order of evaluation matters, maintain it by evaluating all parameters beforehand and cache the results.

Comment: @Destructor to me at least, the question appears ambiguous possibly due to language barrier. Did you mean to ask: "How does leaving argument evaluation order unspecified allow compiler to optimize code" or "How to not specify an exact order of evaluation to help compiler to generate optimized code?" If former, I would recommend also asking "**Does** leaving argument evaluation order unspecified allow compiler to optimize code" which I don't think is something that can be assumed. Also, if you refer to something you have read, please also cite where you've read it.

Comment: @Destructor: Nothing. I think that this is a great question.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: thank you for your appreciation towards my question !!!

Comment: There's a reason C evaluated arguments and pushed them on the stack in right-to-left order. The reason was not optimization. It was so you could have variadic functions like `printf`. The leftmost arguments would be pushed last on the stack and thus be at known offsets relative to the stack pointer. (That also necessitated that the caller, not the callee, adjust the stack on return, because only the caller knows how much was pushed.)

Comment: @Destructor: You're welcome. Thank you for writing it!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the whole premise of the question is wrong:

> How not specify an exact order of evaluation of function argument helps C & C++ compiler to generate optimized code?

It is not about optimizing code (though it does allow that). It is about not penalizing compilers because the underlying hardware has certain ABI constraints.

Some systems depend on parameters being pushed to stack in reverse order while others depend on forward order. C++ runs on all kinds of systems with all kinds on constraints. If you enforce an order at the language level you will require some systems to pay a penalty to enforce that order.

The first rule of C++ is "If you don't use it then you should not have to pay for it". So enforcing an order would be a violation of the prime directive of C++.

Comment: +5 for reminding me about C++ philosophy: _If you don't use it then you should not have to pay for it_

Comment: "If you had a forced order of evaluation the sequence points would force you to make that call twice." Not really. As-if still applies.

Comment: What do you mean by "penalizing"? It's actually about providing more opportunities to optimize the code. Also what ABI constraints does the hardware have? The OS and the compiler define the ABI. In addition, you're misusing the  zero-overhead principle in this context. Finally, the optimization example you provided doesn't work because, in this example, the sub-expression elimination can be performed irrespective of the order of evaluation. I find this answer completely wrong.

Answer (score 7):

**It doesn't**. At least, it doesn't today. Maybe it did in the past.

[A proposal](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0145r1.pdf) for C++17 suggests defining left-right evaluation order for function calls, `operator<<` and so on.

As described in Section 7 of that paper, this proposal was tested by compiling the Windows NT kernel, and it actually led to a speed *increase* in some benchmarks.  The authors' comment:

> It is worth noting that these results are for the worst case scenario where the optimizers have not yet been updated to be aware of, and take advantage of the new evaluation rules and they are blindly forced to evaluate function calls from left to right.

suggests that there is further room for speed improvement.

Answer (score 5):

The order of evaluation is related to the way arguments are passed. If stack is used to pass the arguments, evaluating right to left helps performance, since this is how arguments are pushed into the stack.

For example, with the following code:

```
void foo(bar(), baz());
```

Assuming calling conevention is 'passing arguments through the stack', C calling convention requires arguments to be pushed into stack starting from the last one - so that when callee function reads it, it would pop the first argument first and be able to support variadic functions. If order of evaluation was left to right, a result of `bar()` would have to be saved in the temporary, than `baz()` called, it's result pushed, following by temporary push. However, right-to-left evaluation allows compiler to avoid the temporary.

If arguments are passed through registers, order of evaluation is not overly important.

Comment: It is compiler dependent. See http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/P1ViEE6lb1x6rZnI & http://cpp.sh/8yya observe the output.

Comment: @Destructor: Exactly.

Comment: @SergeyA: You 1st said it is not compiler dependent.

Comment: @Destructor: Don't be rude. And no, it's not incorrect. The order of evaluation is unspecified because it is compiler-dependent as to which order is optimal. Sergey hasn't been terribly clear, granted, but he's given one example of a possible approach.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: what about code portability due to this ?

Comment: @Destructor It is not strictly portable.  If you use unspecifed or undefined behavior you cannot guarantee the behavior.  With unspecified at least you can check the implementation but why use either.

Comment: @Destructor: Code is not portable that depends on an order of evaluation. If you want to have badly written functions that are dependant on global state and want to enforce an order then evaluate them first in a separate statement (assign to references).

Comment: Nothing happens to code portability, because order of evaluation was unspecified. If it would be specified, code portability would suffer, since fixed argument passiing could hurt performance. Writing non-defined code was and alwaways will be non portable even on the same compiler.

Comment: @LokiAstari: but order is strictly specified in other languages like Java, C#, D etc.

Comment: @Destructor: Sure so. These are different languages and they made different choices.

Comment: @Destructor, you are free to use those languages. They do not concern themselves with low-level performance.

Comment: @Destructor C++ tries to allow compilers to do as much optimizing as they can.  One way is to not specify the order of evaluation.  If they stuck with one way then they could be leaving performance on the table and performance is a big part of C++.  If you need a specified order you can manually write the code to get that behavior but now you only pay for that evaluation order when you need it.  In the majority of times where it is not needed you do not have to pay for it.

Comment: @SergeyA: I would also add a section that sub expression evaluation ordering can be optimized away in certain situations thus the order of expression evaluation can affect the order of parameter evaluation.

Comment: @LokiAstari, I am afraid, I am not familiar with the topic enough - may be you can add this part as your separate answer? Or you can edit my answer with specific details and an example for everyone's benefit.

Comment: This performance gain would also depend on "push regname" being the only way of writing the stack.  If you write the stack by indexing off esp or ebp for example, then this is not a problem.

Comment: @M.M. agree completely. Compilers still tend to push as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2):

The original reason that the C and C++ standards didn't specify and an order of evaluation for function arguments is to provide more optimization opportunities for the compiler. Unfortunately, this rationale has not been backed up by extensive experimentation at the time these languages were initially designed. But it made sense.

This issue has been raised in the past few years. See [this](https://herbsutter.com/2014/12/01/a-quick-poll-about-order-of-evaluation/) blog post by Herb Sutter and don't forget to go through the comments.

Proposal [P0145R1](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0145r1.pdf) suggests that it's better to specify an order of evaluation for function arguments and for other operators. It says:

> The order of  expression  evaluation,  as
>   it  is  currently  specified  in  the  standard,  undermines  advices,
>   popular programming idioms, or the relative safety of standard library
>   facilities.  The traps aren’t just for novices or the careless
>   programmer.  They affect all of us indiscriminately, even when we know
>   the rules.

You can find more information about how this affects optimization opportunities in that document.

In the past few months, there has been a very extensive discussion about how this change in the language affects optimization, compatibility and portability. The thread begins [here](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-proposals/Ew_0zQl_yBg) and continues [here](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-proposals/oQUOtYX4R3o). You can find there numerous examples.