# Why doesn't C/C++ sequence modifications?

Tags: c++

```
i = a * 2 + b / 4
```

We know that the `*` and `/` operations are unsequenced. This is easy to understand, because the sequence doesn't matter.

```
i = i++ + i++
```

But what's the exact reason C/C++ doesn't sequence side-effects? Just to make the rules more consistent? Or to optimize something (And make it not working... Doesn't seem to be likely).

Or is it that for something like function calls whether there are side-effects is hard to determine?

Comment: [This article series](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html) goes into some of the reasoning behind UB.

Comment: I ask you, why should the language support `i = i++ + i++;` when you can accomplish the same thing using a more expressive statement, `i += 2;`?

Comment: *"when you can accomplish the same thing using a more expressive statement, `i += 2`*" - there is no *same thing* when the thing you're comparing to has no defined behaviour.  But, whatever the programmer intended could certainly be expressed properly, with defined behaviour.

Comment: @TonyD, it would be the same thing if the language supported sequencing of the term `i++`.

Comment: @RSahu: the "least surprising to beginners" way would likely be to evaluate the left-hand-side `i++` (including the side effect), then the right hand side `i++`, then add the result, then assign back to `i`, giving `i = i + (i + 1)` or `i = 2 * i + 1`, rather than your `i += 2`.  But, some other programmer might expect `i = 2 * i` or even `i = 2 * i + 2`.

Comment: @BlueWanderer: *"Or to optimize something"* <-- this.  And, in the general case it's impractical for the compiler to detect all the situations in which the behaviour needs to be sequenced (it may depend on the run-time values of some variables, or stuff done by out-of-line functions being called), which means safety would require pessimistic assumptions (i.e. generating slower code *"just in case"*).

Comment: @RSahu : something that beginners run into, a function taking two pointers, ptr1 and ptr2, then writing: k = (*ptr1)++ + (*ptr2)++. This seems innocent enough, but if ptr1 == ptr2 ... (this also shows why it's inefficinent to detech and assign non-UB to it).

Comment: perhaps a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37029890/how-not-specify-an-exact-order-of-evaluation-of-function-argument-helps-c-c